# NoMethodError in Articles#show ( undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3c0Z.png)

Am trying to render "latest articles" on my article blog sidebar and am getting the error above, the same code works fine for the article index page but shown errors in the show page.

[latest articles partial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fltC9.png)

and my article controller below.
[articles_controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr6Nx.png)

Comment: undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass means that there is no method each that works with an object class Nil. it works for index method because you are passing variable `@articles` there. But in show you are passing variable called `@article`. So you @articles variable in the show method does not exist so it has a default value nil.

Answer (score 1):

`undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` means that there is no method each that works with an object of class Nil. It works for the #index method because you are passing the variable `@articles` there. But in #show, you are passing a variable called `@article`. So you `@articles` variable in the show method does not exist therefore it has a default value nil. Your code in the index iterates over all articles, that is what `each` is doing. But in #show you want to show only one article so you should skip the `each` block, and use an article like `@article.title`

Answer (score -2):

Found the solution, the code below worked for me.

```
<% Article.all.order("created_at Desc").limit(5).each do | article | %>
<%= article.title %>
<% end %>
```

Note: I ordered and limit the article to 5 at the same time and it's in my VIEW.

Comment: Just a note - this is widely regarded as a bad practice to perform database queries in your views. Your view is now tighly coupled to Article model.

Comment: thanks for the info, so what's the best way to solve this problem because <% @articles.each do | article | %> does not seem to do it for me.

Comment: While answering your own question is a nice way to share knowledge this add zero value for others as the question doesn't actually contain any code and is not answerable. As soon as those links to the images break its completely pointless. Either edit the question until its actually answerable or delete it completely.